# Django UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_user.username

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am implementing a custom Django user from scratch. Almost all things are working, but an issue arises when I create new user from the Django admin panel as follows.

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: accounts_user.username
```

Why does this error occur even if there is no `username` field in my `User` model?
I have included supporting files here.

##### models.py

```py
import uuid

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from .managers import CustomManager
from .utils import path_to_upload


# Create your models here.
class BaseModelMixin(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(_("Created At"), auto_now=True)
    modification_date = models.DateTimeField(_("Modified At"),
                                             auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class User(AbstractUser, BaseModelMixin):

    display_name = models.CharField(_("Display Name"), max_length=200,
                                    blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_("Email Address"), unique=True,
                              blank=False, null=False)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(_("Profile Picture"),
                                    upload_to=path_to_upload)

    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["display_name"]
    objects = CustomManager()
```

---

##### forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password
from django.forms import TextInput, PasswordInput
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from .models import User


class AdminUserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):

    password1 = forms.CharField(validators=[validate_password,],
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Password"}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(validators=[validate_password, ],
                                widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"placeholder": "Confirm Password"}))

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ["display_name", "email", "profile_pic"]
        widgets = {}
        for field in fields:
            if field not in ("password", "profile_pic"):
                widgets[field] = TextInput(attrs={
                    "placeholder": field.replace("_", " ").title()
                })
        widgets["password"] = PasswordInput(render_value=True,
                                            attrs={'required': False})
        widgets["profile_pic"] = forms.FileInput()


class AdminUserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(label=_("Password"), required=True,
                               validators=[validate_password],
                               widget=PasswordInput(render_value=True))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["display_name", "profile_pic", "password"]
        widgets = {}
        for field in fields:
            if not field == "profile_pic":
                widgets[field] = TextInput(attrs={"placeholder": field.replace("_", " ").title()})

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

##### managers.py

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _


class CustomManager(BaseUserManager):

    def create_user(self, display_name, email, password, **extras):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_("Email is a mandatory field"))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(display_name=display_name, email=email, **extras)
        user.set_password(password)
        # user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, display_name, email, password, **extras):
        extras.setdefault("is_staff", True)
        extras.setdefault("is_active", True)
        extras.setdefault("is_superuser", True)

        if "is_superuser" not in extras:
            raise ValueError(_("'is_superuser' is mandatory for superuser"))
        if "is_staff" not in extras:
            raise ValueError(_("'is_staff' is mandatory for superuser"))

        return self.create_user(display_name, email, password, **extras)
```

##### admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin

from . import models
from . import forms


# Register your models here.
class CustomUserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    # add_form = forms.AdminUserRegistrationForm
    form = forms.AdminUserRegistrationForm
    model = models.User
    list_display_links = None
    list_display = ("display_name", "email",)


admin.site.register(models.User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are inheriting from `AbstractBaseUser` and it has `username` field, in order to completely remove it from your model you need to set it as `None` in the custom user class:

```
class User(AbstractUser, BaseModelMixin):
    username = None
    ...
```

Comment: That eliminated that error but brought new one. Now it's saying `NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_user.username`. What it has to do with `username` if it isn't even mentioned.

Comment: did you run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after removing the field?

Answer (score 0):

By default `AbstractUser` has `username` field.

by doing `USERNAME_FIELD = "email"` **username** field won't be removed.
It just tells Django to use `email` as **username** field instead of the actual `username` field.

since the `username` field is **required** and **unique** you need to remove it manually:

```
class User(AbstractUser, BaseModelMixin):
    # ...
    username = None
    # ...
```